# Get Sum of minutes from records in table without calculating overlapping different records in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I want to calculate the sum of minutes between two dates from a table, without overlapping(explaining below after table data)**

```
**Id**        **timeStart**            **timeEnd**          **ReaderId**
3          2019-04-11 21:50:00.00   2019-04-11 22:00:00.00       24 
4          2019-04-11 22:30:00.00   2019-04-11 22:35:00.00       24 
5          2019-04-11 22:31:00.00   2019-04-11 22:33:00.00       22 
6          2019-04-11 21:40:00.00   2019-04-11 21:55:00.00       22
```

** As you can see in above data we have two readers and i want to get sum of minutes from all the records. for example, 3 and 6 rows, in 6th id time is starting from 21:40 and ends on 21:55 and in 3rd ID it is 21:50 to 22:00. **So it should count only between 21:40 to 22:00, so output should be 20 minutes. Should not count double these(21:40-21:55) = 15 + (21:50-22:00)=10 = 25. need to count the overlapping minutes once**

I am not sure, how i can do this. I know below to get time between two dates but not sure how i can overcome the overlapping point.

```
(datediff(minute, @dt_start, @dt_end))
```

**UPDATE:**

from above data in table: 25 Minute should be the output as explained below:
**Original Data**

```
21:50 - 22:00
22:30 - 22:35
22:31 - 22:33
21:40 - 21:55
```

rearranging for bit more easy to understand:

```
21:40 - 21:55
21:50 - 22:00 
22:30 - 22:35
22:31 - 22:33
```

In first two rows, time is starting from 21:40 and max end time is 22:00 so output would be 20 + 5(from last two rows) = 25 Minute.

Comment: You can use lead or lag to find the real start or end time. Personally I would add another working column that gives the true end time. If you can't add columns to this table you can do it inside a table variable or a temp table.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, how with temp table?

Comment: The very last example makes it a lot clearer. So reader is completely irrelevant in your answer. If you extended your final answer to have a column showing what the true end time is (to be used in the calc), as well as the minutes contributed by the row, you would be well on the way to answering your own question.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, if i'll have that column for minutes, it will also consists of overlapping minutes. how i can rid over these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to make it working with below query:

```
Declare @Terms table (Start DATETIME, Finish DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @Terms values
('2019-04-11 21:50:00.00','2019-04-11 22:00:00.00'),
('2019-04-11 22:30:00.00','2019-04-11 22:35:00.00'),
('2019-04-11 22:31:00.00','2019-04-11 22:33:00.00'),   -- overlapping term
('2019-04-11 21:40:00.00','2019-04-11 21:55:00.00')

Select Minutes = sum(Minutes) From (
    Select Distinct 
           B.DateR1
          ,B.DateR2
          ,Minutes = DateDiff(Minute,B.DateR1,B.DateR2)
     From @Terms A
     Cross Apply (
                  Select DateR1=Min(Start)
                        ,DateR2=max(Finish) 
                   From  @Terms 
                   Where Start <= A.Finish and Finish >= A.Start
                 ) B
 ) A
```

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Taking up on your example I have made a simple sample. Assuming that what you want is for each ReaderId

```
SELECT a.ReaderId, a.startDate, a.endDate
INTO #temp
FROM (
SELECT '2019-04-11 21:50:00.00' startDate, '2019-04-11 22:00:00.00' endDate,  24 ReaderId union
SELECT '2019-04-11 22:30:00.00' startDate, '2019-04-11 22:35:00.00' endDate,  24 ReaderId union
SELECT '2019-04-11 22:31:00.00' startDate, '2019-04-11 22:33:00.00' endDate,  22 ReaderId union
SELECT '2019-04-11 21:40:00.00' startDate, '2019-04-11 21:55:00.00' endDate,  22 ReaderId
) a

SELECT ReaderId, MIN(startDate) StartDate, MAX(endDate) EndDate, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(startDate), MAX(endDate)) TotalMinutes
FROM #temp
GROUP BY ReaderId

DROP TABLE #temp
```

In this case it will return the foloowing result:

```
ReaderId    StartDate                 EndDate                TotalMinutes
  22      2019-04-11 21:40:00.00    2019-04-11 22:33:00.00     53
  24      2019-04-11 21:50:00.00    2019-04-11 22:35:00.00     45
```

Comment: This won't account for gaps in the data. @RamSingh please indicate whether there are gaps in the data.

Comment: need to count the overlapping minutes once, not twice.

Comment: Does that last comment mean that 98 is the wrong answer? Please be verbose in your comments.

Comment: yes, it wrong, I am upding my question bit more to explain more

Comment: @RamSingh now it's wrong, after the update information came in. If I have more time I will set it up according to your full explanation.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thanks for asking for more details.

Comment: @Pimenta, so do you get or still need more info?

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
select id, ReaderId, (datediff(minute, isnull(dataset.start_calc, dataset.timeStart), isnull(dataset.end_calc,dataset.timeEnd))) Time_in_minuts
from ( 
select id, 
    a.timeStart  ,
    a.timeend  ,
    (select b.timeEnd  from Reader_timings b where a.id <> b.id and a.ReaderId  = b.ReaderId and b.timeStart between a.timeStart and a.timeEnd) 'start_calc' ,
    (select a.timeEnd from Reader_timings b where a.id <> b.id and a.ReaderId  = b.ReaderId and b.timeEnd between a.timeStart and A.timeEnd  ) 'end_calc',
    ReaderId
from Reader_timings a)
as dataset
```

It will be helpful for you.
tested on

```
create table Reader_timings (id int, timeStart datetime, timeEnd datetime , ReaderId int)

insert into Reader_timings  values (3          ,'2019-04-11 21:50:00.00'   ,'2019-04-11 22:00:00.00'       ,24 )
insert into Reader_timings  values (4 ,         '2019-04-11 22:30:00.00',   '2019-04-11 22:35:00.00',       24 )
insert into Reader_timings  values (5 ,         '2019-04-11 22:31:00.00',   '2019-04-11 22:33:00.00',       22 )
insert into Reader_timings  values (6 ,         '2019-04-11 21:40:00.00',   '2019-04-11 22:55:00.00',       22 )
```